# iOS BAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion

Tags: ios, swift3

I am beginner in iOS developing. I have problem when I try to convert Swift 2 project to Swift 3 project.
Compiler returns next 2 errors:

> '?' must be followed by a call, member lookup, or subscript
>
> Cannot convert value of type '(Bool!, CFError!) -> Void' to expected argument type 'ABAddressBookRequestAccessCompletionHandler!'

for next line:

> ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(nil) {(b : Bool!, c : CFError!) -> Void in completion(b,c)}

Comment: The simplest way of updating is to delete the Swift 2 line and to write it again. Using Xcode's autosuggest feature you will be shown the right method signature to use (this is what has changed).

Comment: did you got the solution for this,i've the same error